# Looking for a classic invasion movie with coffee

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, alien-invasion, b-movies

I am looking for a classic invasion movie (I remember it as black and white) in which aliens conquer the Earth by occupying human bodies which then act 'cold' and weird.

It is pretty much like the Body Snatchers, but in this case, aliens can be recognised by their glowing eyes and, most recognizable, by their extensive thirst for coffee. Should be American or British, although I had seen it on German TV in the early 90s.

Comment: Aliens that stand out for liking coffee? Well well, what will they think of next.